# what is GitStatus for and how to use it

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

I want to write a tool for automerging changes from master into feature branches. I use two tools here, a branchtool which creates new feature branches, the users are able to enable or disable automerge for their feature branches and a automergetool which, runs as a service on the server and needs to read this information and run the merge process.

During my research i discovered GitRef.Statuses and "GitStatus"-Class, which "contains the metadata of a service/extension posting a status" (official microsoft description). GitStatus looks very interesting, because i can define own Statuses and set a state on it. The Problem is, i didn't found anything about it - except MS-Pages, which are not very far-reaching. i don't know whether my procedure is correct or not.
So how can i use it? My intention is this one:

```
public Branch AddStatusToBranch(Branch branch)
{
  if (!(branch.GitBranch.Statuses is List<GitStatus> bGitStatuses))
    bGitStatuses = new List<GitStatus>();

  _status = null;
  if ((_status = bGitStatuses.Find(s => s.Context.Genre == _genre)) != null)
  {
    return branch;
  }
  else
  {
    _status = new GitStatus()
    {
      Context = new GitStatusContext() { Genre = _genre, Name = branch.DisplayName }
    };
    bGitStatuses.Add(_status);
    branch.GitBranch.Statuses = bGitStatuses;
    return branch;
  }
}
```

Maybe there is another - a simpler - way to transport and save this information (which shall not be lost, just when set through the tool or a pullrequest or deletion of this branch happened).

So how to use GitStatus correct?

Kind Regards
Mirko

Comment: How does your tool automatically handle merge conflicts?

Comment: if there are any merge conflicts the automated merge will be withdrawn and the developer will be informed, that master has changes and merge conflicts appear (maybe there will be a solution in the future to automate that as well)

Comment: Seems no problem on your script, did you facing error with this script? Or just want a simpler way to configure the GitStatus class and called it?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT no, there are no issues with that code example, i want to understand gitstatus correctly, as there is not a really documetation to find. can i use it for my purpose or not? Is there any constellation, which could lead to a reset of GitStatus (like merging in another branch where this is not set and so on)?

i need a simple and save way to tell the other tool that automerge is active or not for a specific branch. alternativly we thought about saving a workitem at azure devops to have a save places.

Comment: Does "can i use it for my purpose or not" means that you want to customized the name, descriptions or genre, right? And it could not be override by other action?

Comment: that's correct, Sir. :)

Comment: you can give any gitstatus a context, where yiu can define a genre something like this:
      _status = new GitStatus()
      {
        Context = new GitStatusContext() { Genre = _genre, Name = branch.DisplayName }
      };

Comment: I provide my understanding into below answer, hope it could give you some assistance:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed expression in comment.

In fact, you can refer to the relevant [Rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) doc to get know more about the [GitStatus Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitstatus?view=azure-devops-dotnet-preview). This `GitStatus` only available under `commit`.

Yes, we can give a body to `GitStatus` like

```
_status = new GitStatus()
    {
      Context = new GitStatusContext() { Genre = _genre, Name = branch.DisplayName }
    };
```

But, as I know, here you need also specified one necessary property in the body: `State`. Normally, we define it as:

```
GitStatusState state
```

So, here the basic structure should look like(I just wrote a simple sample):

```
public static GitStatus GetTestGitStatus(GitStatusState state){
            GitStatus myStatus = new GitStatus();
            myStatus.Context = GetTestStatusContext(name, genre);//Context
            myStatus.State = state;//State
}
```

To specified the value to State, you can also directly use

`State = GitStatusState.Succeeded, // GitStatusState.{xxxx}`

---

Since you mentioned in the comment: *whether it could be used for personal purpose and be override by others*.

Of course, yes, it can be used for customized. You can define any thing with that syntax. **Note:** There has one limitation, for `State` value, you must use the one which listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitstatusstate?view=azure-devops-dotnet-preview#fields).

For `Status`, just consider it as an array. This means it will not be override after you specified one customized status content on it. If there is one new status update here, it will be stored into this "array" in turn, and the new status storage location is always `array[0]`.

So, if you want to use it as *telling the other tool that auto merge is active or not for a specific branch*, you need concern that the new status which created by other system actions would cover the location of the one you created previously. I suggest you'd better store the `status id` after you create it, as the identifier of other tools to know the corresponding status.

**Update:** Here the other actions not just limited to your customized action, it also include some system actions, including builds, tests, commits and etc.

Comment: thnaks for you explanation, i will give it a try and reply after evaluating it. :)

Comment: @Mirko, hoping your good news. In addition, in my answer, it was a bit confusing about the usage of `state` and `status`. Has been corrected, you can view the edited answer. Hope not mislead you:-)

Comment: @Mirko, which part are you still facing the confusing?

Comment: whow fast reply :D i just need the existens of the context, the state is not important. I have one additional question, how is gitstatus handeled when i merge a branch into this branch, where this status is not set?

Comment: hahh, because I am on my working time. Yeah, I know it is not important to specify the status value since you just customized the context. It just the one which our server needed. Also, not clear about " where this status is not set" , could express more?

Comment: i just started working (In Germany it is 7 AM). ok, yes it is missleading. The Question is: what happen to gitstatus if you merge two branches together (one has gistatus set, and one not), is this array also merged together and none of the informations is lost or is one side winning?

Comment: @Mirko, as my answered mentioned, it would be override by other action. And this action include our backend script. I just checked our script again, it would create a gitstatus message when the new commit exists. This means, when you merge one branch into the other, the system will automatically create a new gitstatus message into array[0] to override the previous one, since the system detect out the new commit. That's why I suggest you remember the `status id`.

Comment: ok thanks. :) than i just missunderstood your post the first time.

Comment: @Exar666Kun. It's okay. My fault that did not mentioned these automatically backend actions. Would update this into answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202148/discussion-between-exar666kun-and-merlin-liang-msft).